# Как использовать внешний калькулятор bc?

Tags: windows, c++

Мне скинули такой вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char *s;
    char out[100];
    FILE *p = popen("echo " sqrt(2 + 2) + l(6) " | bc -l", "r");
    fgets(out, sizeof out, p);
    out[strlen(out) - 1] = 0;
    printf("%sn", out);
}
```

Но у меня при компиляции ошибка

> `popen: идентификатор не найден.`

Что делать? Работаю в Microsoft Visual Studio 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. bc - это утилита Linux. Чтобы пользоваться ею в Windows, ее нужно установить. Можно взять здесь: [Bc for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/bc.htm).
2. `popen` - это функция для Linux, для Windows надо использовать `_popen`.

Comment: скачал , установил, заменил popen на _popen  - новая ошибка: _popen: функция не принимает 1 аргументов. Что не так ?

Comment: Слеши перед кавычками внутри строки нужно не забывать ставить

    "echo \" sqrt(2 + 2) + l(6) \" | bc -l"